# Display Flash Web Widget in a Delphi form

Tags: delphi, widget

I would like to display the yahoo weather widget (or any similar flash or java based widget) in a Delphi application. I freely admit I don't quite understand what would be required to make this work.

Any suggestions on how this could be accomplished would be appreciated.

I'm using Delphi 7. All of the Widgets are just HTML Code, which when I cut & paste them to my Blogger page for instance, show up and work fine. I'm not sure how to take that same html code and use it in a Delphi form to get similar results.

Detailed instructions would be appreciated as well as an explanation. Clearly I don't quite understand how this works... I only know what outcome I'd like  ;-)

Thanks Rob, it wasn't a memory issue, butt he admins did take care of it as you suggested.

Mark

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you want to host the SWF ActiveXObject.

http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/l/aa040103a.htm

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you could host Flash's active X control for a flash control.

The other option is to use an embedded webpage (possibly loaded off the local disk) using the built in Delphi TWebBrowser control to show any web content including Java or Flash controls (as long as they are installed on the client).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a video on embedding flash into Delphi Applications [Available Here](http://codegearguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=56&Itemid=27).  If the widget is a flash file (.swf) it should be fairly easy.  The other option (as already mentioned) is to use the Delphi TWebBrowser component.