# How to represent data using flash animation using delphi?

Tags: flash, delphi, animation

I have a lot of employee data. Then i want to show to user the data using flash animation.
Is it possible to be done with flash animation with delphi ?

Thanks before..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Flash Web Widget in a Delphi form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094653/display-flash-web-widget-in-a-delphi-form)

Comment: @splash : i think it is different case. i need to represent flash animation which visualize my data. Is there any delphi component to do this ?

Comment: @yudo: The top-voted answer is mentioning this article: [Running Flash animations with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/l/aa040103a.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Delphi component then this could be helpful: http://www.delphiflash.com/

Comment: delphiflash does not support dataset base.. should i use json or xml based ?

Comment: @yuda: A Flash application cannot access directly any database. It has to communicate with a web server which is delivering the data via simple HTTP requests, SOAP, REST or whatever. So embedding the Flash ActiveX should be sufficient if you have a appropriate data backend.

Comment: flash applet can be scriptable, thus there is the way to communicate to the form where ActiveX has been embedded into. Resorting to HTTP for that sounds like overkill for me.

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light : thanks for your suggestions.. i will try first..